# how to use 'group_concat' only to filtered rows from a table mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, group-concat

it has a column `IsDisabled`  i want use `group_concat` only to rows where `IsDisabled=0`

currently i am using

```
select parentid,group_concat(REPLACE(WhatDoYouSell, ',', '')) sales from table_name
group by parentid
```

i want to use group_concat to `WhatDoYouSell` column if only `IsDisabled=0` of that row

i have tried with

```
select parentid,group_concat(REPLACE(WhatDoYouSell, ',', '')) sales from table_name
where IsDisabled=0 
group by parentid
```

it seems that the query ignores all the `group by parentid records` if one of the recoeds `IsDisabled =1`

Answer (score 3):

Try this query with internal condition -

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
  parentid INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  WhatDoYouSell INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  IsDisabled INT(11) DEFAULT NULL
);
INSERT INTO table_name(parentid, WhatDoYouSell, IsDisabled) VALUES
(1, 1, 0),
(1, 2, 1),
(1, 3, 0),
(2, 1, 1),
(2, 2, 1);

SELECT
  parentid,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF(IsDisabled = 0, WhatDoYouSell, NULL)) sales
FROM
  table_name
GROUP BY
  parentid;

+----------+-------+
| parentid | sales |
+----------+-------+
|        1 | 1,3   |
|        2 | NULL  |
+----------+-------+
```

Comment: I simplified the table a little, WhatDoYouSell field created as INT.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT parentid,GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(WhatDoYouSell, ',', '')) sales
FROM (SELECT parentid, WhatDoYouSell FROM  table_name 
WHERE IsDisabled=0 ) AS A
GROUP BY parentid
```

Comment: It's not possible. Upload your create table script with sample data with output which you get after executing my query.